# Android's "Toast" in iOS: adding button to message

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, toast, unrecognized-selector

I have created an iOS class for a ToastView (similar to Android's toast) that displays a message bar at the bottom of the screen.  I added a button to the ToastView, and solved my original error. The NSLog for touching the button shows up in the console, but I need to send a BOOL value back to HomeViewController when the button is clicked and I'm not sure how to communicate between the two with this button.  Any help?

in ToastView.h:

```
+ (void)showToastInParentView: (UIView *)parentView withText:(NSString *)text withDuaration:(float)duration;
+ (void)undoButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

in ToastView.m:

```
//shows the "toast" message
+ (void)showToastInParentView: (UIView *)parentView withText:(NSString *)text withDuaration:(float)duration {
//code to show message
UIButton *undoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(toast.frame.size.width - 60.0, toast.frame.size.height - 35.0, 40, 20)];
undoButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[undoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(undoButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

+(void) undoButtonClicked:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"UNDO BUTTON TOUCHED");
}
```

and I call ToastView with the following code in my HomeViewController:

```
[ToastView showToastInParentView:self.view withText:@"TOAST MESSAGE!" withDuaration:5.0];
```

Comment: Looks like undoButtonClicked is defined as an object method, but you might be calling it directly on the class. Do you use anywhere *[ToastView undoButtonClicked:someParameter];* ?

Comment: If so, let me know if changing it to *[self undoButtonClicked:someParameter];* works better so I can write a complete answer

Comment: I do not.  I'm not sending any parameters to undoButtonClicked:, I just need to know when the button has been touched.  Where would I need to call this in the app?

Comment: That did not work.  When I create the button, this is its responder in ToastView [undoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(undoButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; I would like to for the undoButtonClicked: method to be called within ToastView when the button is clicked in another class

Comment: You need to give more code to work on.. The last part of the last comment is important "clicked in another class", you should probably try to improve your question with more code and context. Let us know by adding a comment when you're done updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your updated code, the problem comes from the `undoButtonClicked:` method, which in your case is a class method (prefixed with "+").

You want to make it an object method by changing the prefix with "-". That way, the class knows it's made to be called on an instantiated object of this class. When you use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`, the action is a selector of your target.

As Apple [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Selector.html):

> A selector is the name used to select a method to execute for an object

So it needs to be an object method, not a class method.

Your code should look like that:

.h:

```
+ (void)showToastInParentView: (UIView *)parentView withText:(NSString *)text withDuaration:(float)duration;
- (void)undoButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

.m:

```
//shows the "toast" message
+ (void)showToastInParentView: (UIView *)parentView withText:(NSString *)text withDuaration:(float)duration {
    //code to show message
    UIButton *undoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(toast.frame.size.width - 60.0, toast.frame.size.height - 35.0, 40, 20)];
    undoButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [undoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(undoButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

-(void) undoButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"UNDO BUTTON TOUCHED");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how then would I be able to return a value from undoButtonClicked: to whatever view controller I call showToastInParentView: from

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog : no direct easy answer for that. I recommend you take a look at protocols and delegates. I'll add this to my answer and let you know.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog : finally I will not add this to my answer as it is a completely different question. You should clean up your code and open a new question for this specific request.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes might look like this in order to work as you desire:

```
@interface ToastView : UIView
- (void)undoButtonClicked:(id)sender;
@end

@interface NotToastView : UIView
@property (weak) ToastView *toastView;
@end

@implementation NotToastView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    UIButton *undoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [undoButton setFrame:self.bounds];
    [undoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(undoButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:undoButton];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)undoButtonClicked:(id)sender {
  [self.toastView undoButtonClicked:sender];
}
@end
```

You would be better off using a delegate protocol here instead of requiring a specific class. The above code does not explicitly set a value to the `toastView` property. It is expected that you are constructing these in a `UIViewController` somewhere and would be setting the value yourself instead of relying on `NotToastView` to set its own `ToastView`.